# How to replace N group with a new one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize

I have this situation, where each Slider + Port is a group:

[image]

Now, Unfortunately I've make the Slider too high. So I need to resize the Height of each (without touch the rest).

Is it possible to replace all groups (i.e. basically the same group copied/pasted N time) with a new one? So in one move I can replace all.

Basically, replace this group:

[image]

with this:

[image]

once, selecting first the groups I need to replace.

Note its not stretched, but only resized the background part (the handle its the same).

Any way?

Comment: Hmmm . . . probably too late now, but if you had turned the graphic into a symbol, and used that symbol in your layout, then you could have just edited the symbol, and all instances would update.

Comment: if you have latest illustrator then you can go to Select - Start Global Edit! if not cc2019 then sorry because you are too late! as @BillyKerr said if you've made it a symbol then edit one can reflect all but without symbol it seems impossible! maybe there might a script but am not sure!

Comment: @DesignPhoenix: I have. What should I need to do?

Comment: posting answer below with image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since You have illustrator 2019**

=> Select the object and go to **`Select - Start Global Edit`**

=> and do whatever you want and it'll reflect to other objects but keep it mind that don't forget to Start global edit again if you change the object

=> note my global edit was for rectangle and i tried to change circle and it's failed for circle! just start global edit every time you swap to another object

[image]

If anyone have same problem and using <2019 illustrator (ie 2018) please follow @Billy kerr answer :) it's quite useful too!

Comment: That's some nice new functionality, but I haven't updated yet for fear of bugs in the new release.  I'll leave my answer up for those who are still using AI CC 2018.

Comment: well it had quite a little bugs but they said they they fixed major bugs XD but everyone knows it won't be stable until christmas XD

Comment: I love final releases lol and well since his artwork was straight common your answer totally legit and can work 100% effectively so +1 for it

Comment: Awesome!!! It works like a charm!!!!

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in my comment, it's probably too late now, but if you had turned the graphic into a symbol, and used that symbol in your layout, then an edit to the symbol would update all instances automatically. This is something to remember for future projects perhaps.

But what's done is done, and you still need a solution.

You could use the Direct Selection tool <kbd>A</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select the top anchors of all the rectangles. Then once selected, use the arrow keys to move them up or down.

For example:

[image]